# jQuery getJSON alert data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with using jQuery getJSON method with alert javascript method. In my Ruby on Rails application I have a simple javascript file that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.getJSON("/users", function(data) {
    alert('It works!');
  });
});
```

Application sends properly request and get proper json but not render this alert.But when I change this to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.get("/survey_result_sets/120", function(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
});
```

then alert is showing properly. Why is that?

UPDATE:
My index action in users_controller looks like this:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: 'It works' }
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you access localhost:3000/users in your browser ??

Comment: My guess is probably you have written the code based on format and you have to access /users.json and not just /users

Comment: Yes, I have defined respond_to block with formats for html and json there.

Comment: When using `$.getJSON` you must return `json` response from server unlike `$.get`!